# Comparing each row to a solutions vector with the correct answer and converting the orginal values based on the solutions in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one data frame containing the original answers and one dataframe that has the solutions to these answers. I want to compare the answers with the solutions and convert the original ones to 1/0 (correct and incorrect, I could use a boolean but for this analysis I require a numeric datatype).

This can easily be done by just using ifelse in transmute I believe, but the problem is that my columns are dynamic. I'm trying to make my script dynamic, so it can adapt to the amount of columns that the test has. So I can't call the columns directly in a logical test.

```
answers <- data.frame(x1 = c(3, 2, 1), x2 = c(2, 1, 2), x3 = c(1, 3, 1))
  x1 x2 x3
  3  2  1
  2  1  3
  1  2  1

solution <- data.frame(x1 = 3, x2 = 2, x3 = 1)
  x1 x2 x3
  3  2  1
```

Goal:

```
  x1 x2 x3
  1  1  1
  0  0  0
  0  1  1
```

I can solve this with a loop in base R, like this:

```
while(i <= nrow(df)){
  z <- 1
  while(z <= ncol(df)){
    if(!is.na(df[i,z])){
      if(df[i,z] == solutions[1,z]){
        df[i,z] <- 1
      }else{
        df[i,z] <- 0
      }
    }
    z <- z + 1
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
```

But I think this is a pretty cumbersome way of achieving this result. I was wondering whether dplyr has an easier way to achieve this? I've looked into using apply, but this is still base R and I'd like to know if this is possible within dplyr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html).

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == df2[[cur_column()]], 1, 0) 
  )
)
```

Assuming that df1 and df2 are your dataframes. Including your data as reproducible dataframes will help people to answer your questions, even if they are simple.

Edit: Thanks @akrun for the correction

Comment: The `df2$.` would be incorrect.  You may need `df2[[cur_column()]]`

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly in addition with akrun's answer. 

Final code:
answers %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == solution[[cur_column()]], 1, 0)))

Answer (score 1):

[@SEcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15492642/secker)'s response is much more elegant, but another alternative would be to pivot the data frames from wide to long in order to make the comparison, although this uses functions from `tidyr` so it's not strictly a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

#create some random data
df <- tibble(X1 = ceiling(runif(10) * 5),
             X2 = ceiling(runif(10) * 5),
             X3 = ceiling(runif(10) * 5))

solutions <- tibble(X1 = ceiling(runif(10) * 5),
                    X2 = ceiling(runif(10) * 5),
                    X3 = ceiling(runif(10) * 5))


#Add a column to track the row, then pivot from wide to long
df %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-row,
               names_to = "column",
               values_to = "answer") %>% 
  #Merge with a similarly transformed solutions df
  inner_join({
    solutions %>% 
      mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
      pivot_longer(-row,
                   names_to = "column",
                   values_to = "solution")
  }, by = c("row", "column")) %>%
  #Check whether the answer matches the soltion
  mutate(is_correct = as.numeric(answer == solution)) %>% 
  #pivot back to wide
  select(row, column, is_correct) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = row,
              names_from = column,
              values_from = is_correct) %>% 
  #no longer need the row
  select(-row)


# A tibble: 10 x 3
X1    X2    X3
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0
2     0     0     0
3     0     1     0
4     0     0     0
5     1     1     0
6     0     0     1
7     1     1     0
8     0     0     0
9     0     1     1
10     0     0     0
```